# How can I change layout params while program is running

Tags: android, layout, parameters, move, margin

I have an ImageView sitting on a FrameLayout. I want to be able to move this imageView by setting a margin:
`LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);`
`lp.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);`
`imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);`
`imageView.invalidate();`
However nothing changes and my imageView does not move. 
What am I doing wrong? 
Do I need to be doing something different other than `imageView.invalidate()` after I set new margins?

Comment: Actually it should be <br> `frameLayout.invalidate();`

Comment: This does not work either as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try This ,I think it will work

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```